# mySQL with php function - inputting data that uses php loop

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, loops

I've created a php function then used a loop to recreate the radio buttons, but now what im struggling with is the function only has one name, but it loops for several different topics. How do i differentiate each answer from one another..? (if that made any sense)

For example; the first two questions, faculty then the basic info i haven't bothered with php due to it not being repetitive enough..

With these i understand that each answer will be paired up with their names, such as faculty, moduleCode etc.

With the php function it looks like this;

```
        }
    echo '<br/><br/>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Then just inserting;

```
  <?php
    ratingLoop(4, 6);
?>
```

where it is needed.

But how would i now separate the question selections as in the function ive only given it the name radioGroup, basically im confusing myself but simply want to know..   How would i take each radio selection from the loop and input it into mySQL if they dont have unique names?

Thank you in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider having another identifier string to pass into the function.

```
function ratingLoop($identifier, $group, $answer){
        for($i = 1; $i <= $group; $i++){
        for($a = 1; $a <= $answer; $a++){
            echo '<input type="radio" name="radioGroup_'.$identifier.'_'.$i." value="'.$a.'">'.$a;
        }
    echo '<br/><br/>';
        }
    }
```

Invoke it like so:

```
   ratingLoop('satisfication', 3, 3);
   ratingLoop('quality_of_service', 3, 3);
```

Comment: How would i give each radio button a name by just adding $group to the function?

Comment: Sorry, quite new to php - i still dont understand the concept.. what would i do with the $i and $a?